# Grand total for each row

Tags: sql, teradata

I have two tables, one containing manufacturing data, one containing repair data.

For my query, the data set is structured like so:

```
MODEL_NAME
PRODUCTION_PROCESS_1
PRODUCTION_PROCESS_2
MFR_DATE
REPAIR_DATE
TOTAL
HARD_DRIVE_SER_NUM
RECEIVER_SER_NUM
```

I need to show ("TOTAL") the total count of receiver models in the fields that have been been repaired and that went through production process 1 and 2.

```
ZR16-500 BALANCERING REWORK 1/2/2010 9/12/2011 147,565 99ZXF A20KTG
ZR22-100 NOBALANCERING PRIME 8/2/2011 3/9/2012 234 92KXF D208FSTXS
ZR16-500 BALANCERING REWORK 1/9/2010 4/2/2012 147,565 G96ZXF A25RSF
...
```

Maybe  "Grand Total" does not apply here.  I welcome any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

PS: I am on Teradata. Not sure if it matters.

Comment: What is in `PRODUCTION_PROCESS_n` when it has not gone through the process yet? Is it NULL?

Comment: No NULL. In fact, it is manufacturing data for goods that have been shipped (sold) to the field. Only four combinations: "BALANCERING/PRIME", "BALANCERING/REWORK" , "NOBALANCERING/PRIME" , "NOBALANCERING/REWORK".

Comment: The structure of the two tables would come in handy. and some vague clue as to how total count of reciever models would be indicated in the data, as well.

Answer (score 0):

This thread can closed. I was just informed by my user that he will be redefining his requirements. Thanks for your time.